# How to track variable's value with chrome debugger tools while it's running

Tags: php, javascript, actionscript-3

Is there way to track the value of a certain variable with chrome debugger while it's running?

I'm debugging a javascript code which contains some variables related to sound. I think these variables are changed every second. I want to track those values, if it's possible. There are four of them. One is the download of the mp3 file itself (I think it's called streaming). The other one is the progress of the playing, and I'm not sure about the rest.

There is a swf file that plays music and the control of it is shown through javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean PHP variables, JavaScript variables, or ActionScript variables? This question is rather ambiguous.

Comment: They're ActionScript variables passed to JavaScript variables, I don't know anything about that swf file

Answer (score 2):

You can use watch expressions in the debugger.

[image: Debugger]

Answer (score 2):

Javascript

```
console.log(someVariable);
```

AS3

```
trace(someVariable);
```

PHP

```
echo $someVariable;
```

C

```
scanf("%s", &someVariable);
printf("%s",someVariable);
```

C++

```
getline(cin, someVariable);
cout << someVariable;
```

Java

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String someVariable = scanner.getLine();
System.out.println(someVariable);
```

Python

```
someVariable = input('Enter some variable: ')
print(someVariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see variables in the console check out [Firephp](http://www.firephp.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to JavaScript variables, then yes, it is possible. Chrome has excellent debugging tools. Try opening the "scripts" tab, finding the section of code you wish to debug, and click on a line number. This will set a break point for that section of code. When that breakpoint is reached, you will see a bunch of information on the right, including the call stack and scope variables. It is here you can track the value of your variables. Another option might be to simply add a `console.log(yourVariable)` to your script and use the console to see what it's value is throughout the execution of your code.

Comment: I didn't know that, but the code isn't mine, is in internet so i can't add it, it use php and swf files.